# How do I prevent InvalidOperationException saving a cyclic graph of entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, cycle, invalidoperationexception

Given the entities,

```
class A {
    B DefaultB { get; set; }
    C DefaultC { get; set; }
}

class B {
    A { get; set; }
}

class C {
    A { get; set; }
}
```

where `A.DefaultB` and `A.DefaultC` are optional,

```
modelBuilder.Entity<A>().HasOptional(x => x.DefaultB).WithMany();
modelBuilder.Entity<A>().HasOptional(x => x.DefaultC).WithMany();
```

what combination of `context.Set<T>().Add(...)` and `context.SaveChanges()` would work to save the following object graph?

```
var b = new B();
var c = new C();
var a = new A { DefaultB = b, DefaultC = c, };
b.A = a;
c.A = a;
// now save these...
```

As it is now, I get an `InvalidOperationException` (collection modification while iterating) because EF [does not seem to handle cycles very well](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adonetefx/thread/39797e39-0dec-4957-bca5-8176fe27b94a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you need to adjust your mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<A>().HasOptional(a => a.DefaultB);
modelBuilder.Entity<A>().HasOptional(m => m.DefaultC);
modelBuilder.Entity<B>().HasRequired(m => m.A);
modelBuilder.Entity<C>().HasRequired(m => m.A);
```

And the correct save order with this mapping:

```
var a = new A() { Id = 3 };
context.As.Add(a);
context.SaveChanges();

var b = new B() { Id = 1};
var c = new C() { Id = 2 };
context.Bs.Add(b);
context.Cs.Add(c);
b.A = a;
c.A = a;
a.DefaultB = b;
a.DefaultC = c;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I think I was prototyping this as you were answering! Confirmed.